# Facing issues when loading from checkpoint in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, roberta-language-model

Im trying to use the below methodology to load my checkpoint however, it throws isADirectoryError when I passed ckpt path as shown in documentation. Here's my code.

```
def main():
   <some data loading code> 


   # init lightning classes
   pl_data_module = PLDataModule(
       train_dataset=train_dataset,
       val_dataset=val_dataset,
       test_dataset=test_dataset,
       predict_dataset=bo_dataset,
       batch_size=pl_finetune_args["batch_size"],
       num_workers=pl_finetune_args["num_workers"],
       random_seed=pl_finetune_args["random_seed"],
   )

   model = PLFineTuneModel(
       pl_finetune_args=pl_finetune_args,
       mlflow_params=mlflow_param,
       predict_file_names = bo_file_names
   )

   model_checkpoint_cb = ModelCheckpoint(
       monitor="val_loss",
       mode="min",
       dirpath=pl_finetune_args["checkpoint_path"],
       filename='best_model',
       save_weights_only=False,
   )

   early_stop_checkpoint_cb = EarlyStopping(
       monitor="val_loss",
       patience=pl_finetune_args["early_stop_patience"],
       mode="min",
       check_on_train_epoch_end=False,
   )

   lr_monitor = LearningRateMonitor(logging_interval='step')

   callbacks = [model_checkpoint_cb, early_stop_checkpoint_cb, lr_monitor]

     mlf_logger = MLFlowLogger(
         experiment_name=mlflow_config["exp_name"],
         tracking_uri=mlflow_config["tracking_uri"],
         run_name=mlflow_config["run_name"],
         run_id=root_run.info.run_id
     )


       trainer = Trainer(
           accelerator="gpu",
           devices=pl_finetune_args["nu_gpu_split"],
           precision=16,
           strategy=pl_finetune_args['strategy'],
           max_epochs=pl_finetune_args["max_epochs"],
           check_val_every_n_epoch=pl_finetune_args["check_val_every_n_epoch"],
           default_root_dir=pl_finetune_args["run_dir"],
           callbacks=callbacks,
           logger=mlf_logger,
           gradient_clip_val=1.0,
           fast_dev_run=pl_finetune_args["fast_dev_run"],
           enable_progress_bar=False,
           log_every_n_steps=1
       )

       if pl_finetune_args['task']=='training':
           logger.info("---Training Started---")
           trainer.fit(model=model, datamodule=pl_data_module)
           logger.info("---Testing Started---")
           trainer.test(model=model, datamodule=pl_data_module, ckpt_path=model_checkpoint_cb.best_model_path)
           logger.info("---Predictions Started---")
           trainer.predict(model=model, datamodule=pl_data_module, ckpt_path=model_checkpoint_cb.best_model_path)

       elif pl_finetune_args['task'] == 'predictions':
           logger.info(f"path: {model_checkpoint_cb.best_model_path}")
           ckpt_path = os.path.join(pl_finetune_args["checkpoint_path"],'best_model.ckpt')
           model = PLFineTuneModel.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_path=ckpt_path)
           trainer.predict(model=model, datamodule=pl_data_module, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I'm taking about the 'predictions' condition
However, I can see that if I remove the below line

`model = PLFineTuneModel.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_path=ckpt_path)`, It first loads the base model, then logs that it restored the weights from ckpt path and predict the files. I wanted to know if it's actually loading the weights or not since it's throwing Directory error when I implemented it as per documentation where it shows something like below -

```
model = MyLightningModule.load_from_checkpoint("/path/to/checkpoint.ckpt")
```

I'm adding my LightningModule snippet I used to load the mode. For context, I have finetuned a roberta model and using it for sequence classification. I want to do some predictions on it. If this is not the right way to load it, please let me know how can I do predictions by loading a model from ckpt path.

This is how I load my model in my PLFinetuneModule - LightningModule

```
def configure_sharded_model(self) -> None:
        self.model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
            pretrained_model_name_or_path=self.model_path,
            num_labels=self.num_labels
        )
```